# ui.router: why is url parameter empty for a parent state when navigating to its child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am trying to get a url parameter at the parent state when navigating to its child states, but at the parent state level, the url parameter is returned as an empty string `""`.

Here's my state config definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("view", {
    url: "/{viewName}",
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
      $scope.viewName = $stateParams.viewName;
    },
    template: "<pre>viewName: {{viewName}}</pre> <div ui-view></div>",
  })
  .state("view.A", {
    url: "^/viewA/{id}",
    template: "<div>content of A</div>"
  })
  .state("view.B", {
    url: "^/viewB/{id}",
    template: "<div>content of B</div>"
  });
```

(full [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8wEach15QhbSAtx98jh?p=preview))

Example urls are:

```
#/viewA/111
#/viewA/222
#/viewB/555
```

What I am trying to get is the view name from the URL (e.g. `"viewA"`) at the parent level.

**Q:** Is it possible to do without resorting to URL regex`ing?

**EDIT**:

An important requirement to note is to be able to navigate to the child state using `ui-sref` or `$state.go`:

```
<a ui-sref="view.A({id: 1})">
```

and have the URL change accordingly. This requirement prevents the approach with relative urls for the child states:

```
.state("view.A", {
    url: "/{id}", // relative URL
    template: "<div>content of A</div>"
  })
```

Comment: Hi, after quick look at the code/problem, my guess is that it could be a bug/(missing feature) of UI-Router. My only suggestion is to post a question to help you with the business requirement, instead of a technical requirement.

Comment: @guzart, thanks. Actually thinking about business requirements led me to realize that this functionality doesn't even fully make sense. I've answered my own question with what I think is a better approach anyway for my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve for the case above, one can define the `viewName` in the custom data field of each child:

```
.state("view.A", {
  url: "/viewA/{id}",
  template: "<div>content of A</div>",
  data: {
    viewName: "viewA"
  }
})
.state("view.B", {
  url: "/viewB/{id}",
  template: "<div>content of B</div>",
  data: {
    viewName: "viewB"
  }
});
```

and use the `$state` variable to `$watch` for changes in `$state.$current.data`:

```
.state("view", {
  controller: function($scope, $state){
    $scope.$state = $state; // need to watch $state, not $state.$current
    $scope.$watch("$state.$current.data.viewName", function(val){
      $scope.viewName = val;
    });
  },
  template: "<pre>viewName: {{viewName}}</pre> <div ui-view></div>",
});
```

Note, that you cannot just get or watch for `$state.$current.data.viewName`, because parent's controller runs only once for any changes in state between its descendants.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgcNhEzirRgj7AcQKKzu?p=preview)

**Does using $stateParams even make sense?**

The URL parameters of the parent state are not defined, presumably because the child state is using an absolute URL, so, the URL definition of the parent (with the requested url parameter) is not used.

Although, it seems in the example described above that this is an omission of functionality, the more I think about this, this functionality does not even fully make sense. What if the parent's URL is completely different from the child:

```
.state("parent", {url: "/parent/{something}"})
.state("child",  {url: "^/child"})
```

What should `$stateParams.something` be equal to?